# Issues compiling client_test.cpp using g++ on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: c++, g++, libtorrent

I am trying to compile one of the sample programs that libtorrent provides called client_test.cpp. This is the code:

http://pastebin.com/PWBhCXkY

I am compiling with this command:

```
g++ client_test.cpp -DBOOST_ASIO_SEPARATE_COMPILATION -I/usr/local/include -o client_test >& log
```

This is the error log:

http://pastebin.com/YF4VGVWr

Thanks for any help, and let me know if there is any other information that I should provide to help diagnose the problem.

Comment: That's an awful lot of code and an awful lot of errors. And we're not really a debugging service. Have you tried fixing it yourself? Maybe you should go ask this question in the place you've got the code from? Or maybe study some manual that's included with it?

Answer (score 1):

As Pawel said, this is an awful lot of code...

I see a lot of incomplete type errors. This kind of error happens when you try to allocate space for a structure not yet fully implemented/known, and so the compiler can't allocate it correctly and returns this error.

For example here:

```
class A {
      A aVariableOfTypeA;
      ...
}
```

you would get the same error.

To fix this you need to use a pointer:

```
class A {
      A* aVariableOfTypeA;
      ...
}
```

At the moment the compiler find the member variable (aVariableOfTypeA), the type "Class A" will be already defined, and so allocating space for the pointer is legal, because a pointer takes a known amount of memory (say the size of a memory word).

So take a look at your code and see if you find anything similar to what I wrote above.
Hope this helps!

---To address the comment from πάντα ῥεῖ

In my example you don't need forward declaration because the member variable type is its own class.
However, consider this:

```
class A {
 A* memberA;
 B* memberB;
};

class B {
 A* memberA;
 B* memberB;
}
```

In this case you need to use forward declaraion, for at the moment you are defining A you make use of a type not yet defined (B), and so you need to let the compiler know what B is supposed to be.

With forward declaration:

```
class B; //Letting the compiler know that B will be a class;
class A {
 A* memberA;
 B* memberB;
};

class B {
 A* memberA;
 B* memberB;
}
```

Comment: _"To fix this you need to use a pointer:"_ ... and a forward declaration!

Comment: You don't need to use a forward declaration in this case.
class A { A* a; }; A a; A b; b.a = &a; works just fine.

Comment: _"You don't need to use a forward declaration ..."_ Yes, but it's the better choice in most cases (along omitting the `#include` statement for a class declaration to depend on)

Comment: Alright, I included it in the explanation. Thanks for pointing it out.